# GetAddrInfo when SSH has bizarre behavior

Tags: centos, ssh

I have a server that is hosted on Rackspace. Let's call the server foo. The server foo's domain (it's a web server) is hosted on DNSMadeEasy. I have noticed some bizarre behavior with this set up and am hoping to make sense of it.

When I SSH to server foo from my AWS/GCE infrastructure, I get this warning message:

```
[user1@bastion-server ~]$ ssh foo
reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.static.cloud-ips.com [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Last login: Tue Feb 19 16:56:30 2019 from xx.xx.xx.xx
[user1@foo ~]$
```

I understand how to fix this, I can do one of two things:

- Add entry into `/etc/hosts` or add a PTR record into DNS server hosted by rackspace.

I can't add the PTR in DNSMadeEasy since the IP itself resolves to rackspace's DNS. We don't have DNS set up in rackspace since it is hosted on DNSMadeEasy. But here is where it get's weird. I can SSH from my local PC or one of my physical servers to foo and I won't get that warning message. I don't have any entries in /etc/hosts so I can't see why this isn't occurring. Can anyone tell me why this occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local PC only finds 1 hostname for the IP it is requesting, from wherever it is making that request.  If you do an nslookup from your local PC, then compare those results to what you see if you do the nslookup from the bastion-server, it is likely that you will find the addressing-source difference that is resulting in your experience.

Comment: So what your saying is: I am seeing the DNS view of what I have configured in DNSMadeEasy vs Rackspace's DNS?

Comment: That seems most likely based on your description.

Comment: Absolutely makes sense. Thanks for clarifying that with me.